# How do I appropriately pass associated array values through SED?

Tags: arrays, bash, sed, associative-array, substitution

I'm creating a Caesar cipher that substitutes the letter in a word with the matching letter if the alphabet were reversed. The sample is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". The output of the following code produces "abcdefghijklmmlkjihgfedcba". The desired output is the alphabet in reverse, but once the editor hits the midpoint, it goes back in reverse instead of going on through to the end.

```
declare -A origin

x=({a..z})
z=({z..a})

for i in {0..25}
do
    origin[${x[i]}]=${z[i]}
done

for x in "${!origin[@]}"
do
    sed -i 's/'${x}'/'${origin[${x}]}'/g' test.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem. Thank you both for your help!

```
#!/bin/bash

#Retrieve the desired shift from user
echo "What number do you want to use for the shift?"
read num

#Create an array of all letters
x=({a..z})

#Take user input and use to create the cipher array
case "$num" in
    0)
    y=({a..z})
    ;;
    1)
    y=({{b..z},a})
    ;;
    2)
    y=({{c..z},a,b})
    ;;
    3)
    y=({{d..z},a,b,c})
    ;;
    4)
    y=({{e..z},a,b,c,d})
    ;;
    5)
    y=({{f..z},{a..e}})
    ;;
    6)
    y=({{g..z},{a..f}})
    ;;  
    7)
    y=({{h..z},{a..g}})
    ;;
    8)
    y=({{i..z},{a..h}})
    ;;
    9)
    y=({{j..z},{a..i}})
    ;;
    10)
    y=({{k..z},{a..j}})
    ;;
    11)
    y=({{l..z},{a..k}})
    ;;
    12)
    y=({{m..z},{a..l}})
    ;;
    13)
    y=({{n..z},{a..m}})
    ;;
    14)
    y=({{o..z},{a..n}})
    ;;
    15)
    y=({{p..z},{a..o}})
    ;;
    16)
    y=({{q..z},{a..p}})
    ;;
    17)
    y=({{r..z},{a..q}})
    ;;
    18)
    y=({{s..z},{a..r}})
    ;;
    19)
    y=({{t..z},{a..s}})
    ;;
    20)
    y=({{u..z},{a..t}})
    ;;
    21)
    y=({{v..z},{a..u}})
    ;;
    22)
    y=({{w..z},{a..v}})
    ;;
    23)
    y=({{x..z},{a..w}})
    ;;
    24)
    y=({{y..z},{a..x}})
    ;;
    25)
    y=({{z..z},{a..y}})
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Sorry, you must use a shift from 0 to 25."
    ;;
esac

#create the string variables for manipulation
fromset=""
toset=""

#place the alphabetic arrays into the atring variables
for i in {0..25}
do
    fromset="$fromset${x[i]}"
    toset="$toset${y[i]}"
done

#Use sed text transformations to alter given files
sed "y/$fromset/$toset/" original.txt > encoded.txt
sed "y/$toset/$fromset/" encoded.txt > decoded.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget **character indexes** in bash. In your script, there is no need for the first 2 **indexed arrays** `x & y`. Example:

```
declare -A origin

x=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
z=zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba

for i in {0..25}; do
    origin[${x:i:1}]=${z:i:1}
done
```

Nothing like substituting `origin[{a..z}]` for `{z..a}` and getting a familiar looking result back? Look for example at the **first** and **last** iterations only. On the **first iteration**, you substitute all `a`'s with `z`'s. Then on the **last iteration** you again substitute all the `z`'s (including those your previously replaced `a->z` in the first iteration) with `a`'s again -- effectively undoing your changes.

A better example is to look at the midpoint of the alphabet `m->n`.

```
x=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
z=zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
              ||
```

When your iteration reaches `m`, you substitute all `m`'s with `n`'s. Then the very next iteration, you substitute `n`'s with `m`'s.

You can see how this happens to look like only half of the substitutions are being effected. After you reach the midpoint in origin, any substitutions only occur **once** since you are no longer encountering letters you have already substituted.

The solution using `tr` previously posted looks like one of your best options.

Answer (score 0):

The aproach you used to pass the associative array is correct, but the logic of the Ceasar cipher is wrong.

Because for each iteration of the `for` loop the `sed` command changes some characters in the input file. This character can be the character originally in the input file, or a character which was previously changed by an earlier sed.  So the `for` loop in effect would do multiple conversion than doing a single conversion.

For example

Consider an input file

```
$ cat test
a z
```

Now a small formated script would be

```
for x in "${origin[@]}"; do     sed -i  "s/$x/${origin[$x]}/g" test; echo "$x ${origin[$x]}";  done; 
z a
y b
x c
w d
v e
..
..
```

Here in the first iteration, the `sed` would change the `z` to `a`. Now the input file would be

```
$cat test
a a
```

Now at the 25th iteration the `$x` will be `a`, Which will convert both the `a`s in the input to `z`

```
$ cat test
z z
```

---

**Alternate solution**

An alternate solution can be written using `tr` as

```
$ a=$(echo {z..a} | tr -d " ")

$ b=$(echo {a..z} | tr -d " ")

$ echo {a..z} | tr $b $a
z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a
```

Why does it work?

Here the characters are read from the input and changed with corresponding character in the `tr` argument, This ensures that a single character is changed only once.